# How to get the ROM Name from Android programatically

Tags: android, rom

I am working on android project and I wish to to retrieve the ROM name (not Android OS name) I.e. CyanogenMod Nightly 11.

Is this possible Google doesn't seem to be finding anything.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using `Build.DISPLAY` most of the ROM's override it, although it's a developer choice so you can't trust it will work 100%

Comment: This appears to work. Not sure why it got downvoted though. Thanks for the help